# forward declaration + typedef change class attributes?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang

I am compiling this code in AppleClang 12.0.5, using command:

```
clang++ -O2 -g -fvisibility=hidden -std=c++17 -Wpedantic -c sharedlib.cpp
```

and I am checking list of symbols in object file via:

```
nm -om sharedlib.o | c++filt | grep "typeinfo for"
```

Code itself (sharedlib.cpp):

```
namespace Foo
{
template <class T>
class BarHidden;

class BarExported;
}

typedef Foo::BarHidden<double> BarHiddenTypedef;
typedef Foo::BarExported BarExportedTypedef;

namespace Foo
{
template<typename T>
class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) BarHidden
{
public:
    virtual ~BarHidden(){};
};

class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) BarExported
{
public:
    virtual ~BarExported(){};
};
}

void __attribute__((visibility("default"))) Throw()
{
    // throw Foo::BarExported();    // weak external typeinfo for Foo::BarExported
    // throw Foo::BarHidden<int>(); // weak external typeinfo for Foo::BarHidden<int>
    throw Foo::BarHidden<double>(); // weak private external typeinfo for Foo::BarHidden<double>
}
```

Can someone explain why 1st and 2nd throw leave visible external typeinfo (expected), but third throw leaves typeinfo symbol with hidden visibility? It looks like typedef instantiates Foo::BarHidden with incorrect visibility attribute (I blame typedef because compiler produces visible typeinfo if I remove BarHiddenTypedef typedef), but is this behavior expected? Is it possible to disable it? I have huge codebase that can potentially have problems of this kind, and I want to be sure all typeinfos of my dylib are visible.

Comment: You'll have to ask the folks who wrote the compiler that you're using. `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` is not standard C++.

Comment: I agree, but maybe someone here knows the reason of such compiler implementation.

Comment: I think it is because the typedef declares an implicit instantiation (which is an incomplete type since the class declaration hasn't been seen yet). The throw expression doesn't instantiate it from the class declaration when the throw expression is handled because it has already been instantiated. Try moving the typedefs to after the template classes are defined.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, of course it works after I move typedefs after class definition, or after declaration that is declared with default visibility. The problem is that in huge project it is impossible to keep such things under control when everyone is making forward declarations in header files which get included in random order.